# Pass a table method to addLink method of a QueryBuildDataSorce object

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

Is there any way to pass a table method instead of fieldid to addLink method of a QueryBuildDataSource object?
I have this code:

```
qbdsLedgerTrans.addLink(
        FieldNum(LedgerTable, AccountNum), // Here i need to pass a conditional value of a LedgerTable method instead of a field
        FieldNum(LedgerTrans, AccountNum)
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no because the query API is tightly bound to tables in SQLServer and tables does not contain any method in SQLServer.

The #addLink will be used to generate query join statement so there must use data present inside the database and method are not in the database but in the aod files.

Depending on what you want to do you can have a method to encapsulate your logic and return the corrected fieldId.

Comment: The problem of encapsulate a logic is that the value that returns this method is a field that belongs to another table and i obtain an error that says that the combination of a field and related field is not valid.

Comment: can you be more precise about you try to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the `addLink` method *must* be an field of the prior joined table, in this case `LedgerTable`. It may be returned by a function, but I doubt it will solve your hidden (unstated) problem.

The second argument to the `addLink` method *must* be an field of the current datasource table.

In other scenarios (form delayed joins) you could use the `addDynalink` method instead.